# Conditional Percentile Rank in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rank

I currently have a percentile rank of a column's values using df.rank as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

columns=['Country','Score']
data=[('US',5),('US',3),('US',12),('US',7),('US',47),('US',87),('US',97),
('US',55),('Brazil',15),('Brazil',32),('Brazil',62),('Brazil',71),
('Brazil',7, ('Brazil',57),('Brazil',45),('Brazil',57)]

df=pd.DataFrame(columns=columns,data=data)
df['Rank']=df['Score'].rank(pct=True)
df

    Country Score   Rank
0   US      5       0.12500
1   US      3       0.06250
2   US      12      0.31250
3   US      7       0.21875
4   US      47      0.56250
5   US      87      0.93750
6   US      97      1.00000
7   US      55      0.62500
8   Brazil  15      0.37500
9   Brazil  32      0.43750
10  Brazil  62      0.81250
11  Brazil  71      0.87500
12  Brazil  7       0.21875
13  Brazil  57      0.71875
14  Brazil  45      0.50000
15  Brazil  57      0.71875
```

How would I calculate the percentile rank based on only the scores for an item's country? So items in the US would be ranked relative to only US items and items in Brazil would be ranked relative only Brazil items?

I have many more countries than displayed here, so performing individually (i.e., `df[df.Country=='US']...` or iterating over a loop does not seem like the most efficient way.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out, but open to other suggestions...

```
df['Country_Rank'] = df.groupby(['Country'])['Score'].rank(pct=True)
df

    Country Score   Rank    Country_Rank
0   US      5       0.12500 0.2500
1   US      3       0.06250 0.1250
2   US      12      0.31250 0.5000
3   US      7       0.21875 0.3750
4   US      47      0.56250 0.6250
5   US      87      0.93750 0.8750
6   US      97      1.00000 1.0000
7   US      55      0.62500 0.7500
8   Brazil  15      0.37500 0.2500
9   Brazil  32      0.43750 0.3750
10  Brazil  62      0.81250 0.8750
11  Brazil  71      0.87500 1.0000
12  Brazil  7       0.21875 0.1250
13  Brazil  57      0.71875 0.6875
14  Brazil  45      0.50000 0.5000
15  Brazil  57      0.71875 0.6875
```